# In which cases is the inverse of a matrix equal to its transpose?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, orthogonal-matrices

In which cases is the inverse of a matrix equal to its transpose, that is, when do we have $A^{-1} = A^{T}$? Is it when $A$ is orthogonal?

Comment: I will post a new question as this is not what I've asked at the title. Sorry for the invonvenience :S
What I asked at the title was answered :)

Comment: Look OK now. ${}{}$

Answer (score 76, accepted):

If $A^{-1}=A^T$, then $A^TA=I$. This means that each column has unit length and is perpendicular to every other column. That means it is an orthonormal matrix.

Comment: at the risk of reviving a dodgy question, may I ask "why" the geometric interpretation of *orthogonal matrix* is equivalent to the algebraic definition you gave? I know the property, but I don't understand it.

Comment: @TrevorAlexander: Think of $A$ as an arrangement of $n$ columns (each $n$ elements tall). Then the $(i,j)$ element of $A^TA$ is the dot product of the $i^\text{th}$ and $j^\text{th}$ columns of $A$ since the $i^\text{th}$ row of $A^T$ is the $i^\text{th}$ column of $A$.

Comment: could you give me confidence that this is actually an "if and only if"? I mean that **both** directions hold: $A^{-1} = A^\top \Leftrightarrow A^\top A = I$

Comment: @MillaWell: $A^{-1}=A^T\implies A^TA=I$: Multiply both sides on the right by $A$. $A^TA=I\implies A^{-1}=A^T$: By definition.

Answer (score 9):

You're right. This is the definition of orthogonal matrix.